# React Visual Studio Code invalid options object error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

for first time i'm installing react to VS Code. done all steps,succesfully created directory but when i write "npm start" to start server ,it errors;

```
PS C:\Users\01!\Desktop\weather-react-app> npm start

> weather-react-app@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Invalid options object. React Refresh Plugin has been initialized 
using an options object that does not match the API schema.       
 - options.overlay.module: The provided value "C:\\Users\\01!\\Desktop\\weather-react-app\\node_modules\\react-dev-utils\\refreshOverlayInterop.js" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.
```

it could be stupid, but I checked the file that mentioned in the error message, there is no "(!)" . How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not complaining about the file, it's complaining about the directory - `C:\\Users\\01!\\`

Comment: ooooh ok.yes. should i change my computer's user name?

Comment: If you can or just place it outside that user's directory